# How change encoding in MemoryStream (use that to create pdf)

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, itext

Have piece of code like below:

```
    var workStream = new MemoryStream();
    var doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;
    doc.Open();
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("MY LONG HTML TEXT");
    var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(builder.ToString()), null);
    foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
        doc.Add(htmlElement);
    doc.Close();
    byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
    workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
    workStream.Position = 0;
    return new FileStreamResult(workStream, "application/pdf")
```

And problem - i want to have some polish letters in my pdf (like "ą","ę" etc.)
How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iTextSharp 5 polish character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902033/itextsharp-5-polish-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a font and then specify the encoding by using stylesheets:

```
FontFactory.Register("c:\\windows\\fonts\\tahoma.ttf");

StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FONTFAMILY, "tahoma");
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, "Identity-H");               

var html = @"data";
var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(html), styles);
```