# iTextSharp SetListSymbol does not work

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to set styling in PDF generated from iTextSharp.

It seems the `SetListSymbol` is not working for me whenever I am trying to set Symbol to list items.

Below is the code that I used:

```
var elements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(overviewReader,null);

foreach (var element in elements)
{
    //element
    var list = element as List;
    if (list != null)
    {
        //list.Symbol.GetImage();
        list.SetListSymbol("\u25A0");
        list.IndentationLeft = 20f;
        doc.Add(list);
    }
    else
    {
        doc.Add(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side-note, HTMLWorker has been discontinued in favor of [XMLWorker](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/)

Comment: Can you post the HTML that it doesn't work with. I just tried it with `<ul><li>Test</li></ul>` and it worked as expected. Also, please remember that whatever font you are using must also support that symbol.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I think your suggestion is possible, however I am struggling to find a nice way of setting font to list items, could you point me a direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTMLWorker` within iText and iTextSharp supports some very limited "stylesheets" via `iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet`. These stylesheets are loosely based on HTML/CSS properties but only the most basic (think HTML 3.2).

The three main things that you want to do are (1) load a font, (2) create a `StyleSheet` pointing to that font and (3) bind the `StyleSheet` to the `HTMLWorker`. I'm going to partially lift some code from my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10336531/231316).

iTextSharp doesn't automatically spider the entire system looking for fonts so you need to manually register them. (Actually, there is a method that you can call and tell iTextSharp to guess at loading fonts but this is much faster.)

Step #1, load the font, in this case Curlz

```
//Path to our font
string OurFont = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "CURLZ___.TTF");
//Register the font with iTextSharp
iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(OurFont);
```

Step #2, create a `StyleSheet` and point it to our font. I'll also set some other properties just to show them off.

```
//Create a new stylesheet
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
//Set the default body font to our registered font's internal name
ST.LoadTagStyle(iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.LI, iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.FACE, "Curlz MT");
ST.LoadTagStyle(iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.LI, iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.COLOR, "FF0000");
ST.LoadTagStyle(iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.LI, iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.SIZE, "50");
```

Step #3, bind the `StyleSheet` to our `HTMLWorker`

```
//Use our StyleSheet from above when parsing
var elements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(overviewReader, ST);
```

Below is a full-working C# WinForms app targeting iTextSharp 5.2.0 that shows off all of the above.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //Path to our font
            string FontArial = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "CURLZ___.TTF");
            //Register the font with iTextSharp
            iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(FontArial);

            //Create a new stylesheet
            iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
            //Set the default body font to our registered font's internal name
            ST.LoadTagStyle(iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.LI, iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.FACE, "Curlz MT");
            ST.LoadTagStyle(iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.LI, iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.COLOR, "FF0000");
            ST.LoadTagStyle(iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.LI, iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.SIZE, "50");

            //Sample HTML
            var html = @"<ul><li>Test</li></ul>";
            //File to output
            var outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf");
            //Basic PDF creation, nothing special here
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER)) {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
                        doc.Open();
                        //Bind a reader to our HTML
                        using (StringReader overviewReader = new StringReader(html)) {
                            //Use our StyleSheet from above when parsing
                            var elements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(overviewReader, ST);
                            //Loop through each element
                            foreach (var element in elements) {
                                //See if the element is a list item
                                var list = element as List;
                                if (list != null) {
                                    //Set some properties
                                    list.SetListSymbol("\u25A0");
                                    list.IndentationLeft = 20f;
                                }
                                //Add the element to the document
                                doc.Add(element);
                            }
                        }
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(format), null);

```
                foreach (IElement element in objects)
                {

                    List list = new List();
                    list.SetListSymbol("\u2022");
                    list.IndentationLeft = 20f;                        
                    list.Add(element);
                    if (list.Chunks.Count == 0)
                    {
                        doc1.Add(element);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        doc1.Add(list);
                    }
                }
```