# How to display Unicode characters in iTextSharo by using C# on MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I want convert **HTML** to **PDF** by using [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/), work success for **English** characters but when using **Unicode** characters PDF convert but dose not display Unicode characters

[This answer not help me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10336531/10250108)

Thanks for help :)

**My Code**

```
public ActionResult Export()
    {
        Byte[] bytes;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();

                    var example_html = @"<p> سڵاو</p>";
                    var example_css = @".headline{font-size:200%}";

                    using (var htmlWorker = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(doc))
                    {
                        using (var sr = new StringReader(example_html))
                        {
                            htmlWorker.Parse(sr);
                        }
                    }


                    using (var srHtml = new StringReader(example_html))
                    {
                        iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                    }

                    using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css)))
                    {
                        using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html)))
                        {
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                        }
                    }


                    doc.Close();
                }
            }

            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
    }
```

Comment: Try specifying html charset. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative a Way**

I try use **Rotativa** it's easy to use, and it follow the same architecture of MVC

> PM > Install-Package Rotativa.MVC -Version 2.0.3

**USE**

```
try
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("Contact"); // this view or html for convert PDF
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return RedirectToAction("GeneralError", "Error");
}
```