# iTextSharp and special characters (slovak graphemes)

Tags: utf-8, itext, pdf-generation, special-characters, encode

I am having trouble with some special slovak characters (for example č, ň and ť). They are disappearing in the itextsharp generated pdf.

From what I've been able to find, this problem has to do with encoding of my `BaseFont`. Currently I am using this:

```
BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
```

Someone suggested that this should work:

```
BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
```

But it throws this exception error:

```
System.ArgumentException was caught
Message='Identity-H' is not a supported encoding name.
Parameter name: name
ParamName=name
Source=mscorlib
```

Anyone know a possible reason and solution to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA ...
```

`BaseFont.HELVETICA` is a [standard type 1 font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_.28Standard_14_Fonts.29) and can't be used for your slovak characters. You need to use a font with the correct glyphs:

```
string FONT = "c:/windows/fonts/arialbd.ttf";
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, STREAM);
  document.Open();
  BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(
    FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED
  );
  document.Add(new Paragraph("č, ň and ť", new Font(bf, 12)));
}
```